# Ansible `where` clause for “Is those host in that group?”

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an ansible (v2.9.6) task which should only be run for hosts in a specific group. How do I write a `where` clause to match that?

```
when: "'my_group_name' in {{ group_names }}"
```

gives me the following error

```
fatal: [hostname1.example.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check ''my_group_name' in {{ group_names }}' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'string'. String: {% if 'my_group_name' in [u'apache_webservers', u'my_group_name', u'webservers', u'ubuntu_servers'] %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: test playbook
  hosts: all
  vars:
    my_group: openvpn

  tasks:
  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: 'my_group is: {{my_group}} , group_names are: {{group_names}}'

  - debug:
      msg: 'condition passed'
    when: my_group in group_names
```

result:

```
PLAY [test playbook] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]
ok: [host2]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "my_group is: openvpn , group_names are: ['openvpn']"
}
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "my_group is: openvpn , group_names are: ['openvpn']"
}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "condition passed"
}
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "condition passed"
}
```

tested on ansible 2.9.6

Answer (score 0):

Start a new play, which can be in the same playbook file.

```
- name: Deploy thing 
  hosts: my_group_name

  tasks:
  - name: Do thing
    debug:
      msg: thing
```

Not the when condition you asked for. However, more clear as to what is going on, as the play only runs hosts matching the pattern.